# Programmatically determine the macro security level

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I made an outlook macro that is widely used in my company. I have just recently been able to sign it with a certificate, so that the security level can be set to a higher level.

I would like to run a check at startup to suggest my users to raise that security level, but I haven't been able to find a way to determine the current security level.

I am still looking, but so far I couldn't find anything in the 'application' members or in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macro Security Settings are stored in the Windows Registry in the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.x\Outlook\Security` in the value `Level`. (Replace `xx.x` with your version number of Outlook.)
The numeric values are:

```
4 = Disable all macros
3 = Notification for digitally signed macros
2 = Notifications for all macros
1 = Enable all Macros
```